# jquery scripts inside a page called via an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, call

So, these script don't want to work. Not sure what to do. If i run the page B by itself, everything works fine. If the page A makes an ajax call to page B, none of the scripts within there would work. What do i do? 
thanks in advance.

the code in page B:

```
  chkBox = function() {
       jQuery("#docheckchildren").checkboxTree({
   collapsedarrow: "../img/img-arrow-collapsed.gif",
   expandedarrow: "../img/img-arrow-expanded.gif",
   blankarrow: "../img/img-arrow-blank.gif",
   checkchildren: true,
   checkparents: false
   });
}
```

page A ajax call:

```
$.ajax({  
     type: "GET",        
     url:"mypage.cfm",
     data:formData,        
     cache:false,       
     success: function(res) { 
     $('#dsp_Grid').html(res);
     chkBox();
     }
    , error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
        confirm('Error! ' + status +':'+ err);
     }
  });
```

page B:
if i have to run it by itself, I have to add the following:
  << the href is different in top pageA: Seems to work since I see the css for the checkboxes.

(Same, src is different in pageA)

I think part of the problem is I am loading whatever returns from pageB to a div in pageA by

```
$('#dsp_Grid').html(res)
```

Comment: This question requires more substance. I don't even know what you're really talking about. Are you saying your page works when you use plain old POST'ing and doesn't when you're using AJAX methods?

Comment: Code, please? We can't help if we don't see the code.

Comment: there is a lot of code, i will try to post the most relevant piece. I am using a checbox tree plugin. Once you check the top level checkbox, it automaticall checks the ones underneath. This piece of code is located in page B. Page A, makes the call via ajax with:

     $.ajax({  
   type: "GET",        
   url:"myURL.cfm",
   data:formData,        
   cache:false,       
   success: function(res) { 
   $('#dsp_Grid').html(res);
   chkBox();
      }
     , error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
   confirm('Error! ' + status +':'+ err);
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Use a call back function in the AJAX call that calls the scripts that is loaded via AJAX or
2. Use the [live query](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) feature that will apply whatever functionality on your page to the newly loaded content.